# error al validar en la interfaz

Tags: mvc, odoo

estoy haciendo pruebas en mis modulos de odoo que tengo instalados pero a la hora de validar y confirmar un formulario y me manda un error de permisos pense que era por parte de mi codigo pero no el error esta en la interfaz que tendría que hacer para que no mande ese error porque estuve revisando los permisos y si muevo algo me manda un error y no me deja revisar el registro

Adjunto imagenes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
esto lo manda en la interfaz de odoo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
y eso manda en la terminal no adjunto codigo por que no tengo error en el código si no el error es de la interfaz que permisos o como podría corregir ese error

Comment: Cómo que no tienes error en el código? Y que es, caso mágico de odoo? Y si no hay ningún error, por qué se está intentando guardar un `null` en una columna que está anotada como `not-null`?? Algo raro hay, yo diría que algún error debe de haber... De hecho la propia consola te indica el error exacto, `product_id` no puede ser null.

Comment: lo curioso que ese campo no lo tengo en el codigo

Comment: si no eso lo esta mandando en un modelo directo de la interfaz

Comment: Me imagino que estas creando de manera programatica un `stock.move`. Ese modelo requiere que le agregues un `product_id` y tiene la propiedad `required=True`, de manera que no acepta nulos. Revisa tu código y agrega esa propiedad al crear el nuevo registro. El mensaje es muy claro; si estas creando, te falta ese campo, si estas eliminando, no puedes por que otro registro necesita ese.

Comment: listo hice eso cambios y si quedo gracias